# Freshly repainted hood looks blurry

Tags: paint

Had my hood repainted due to chipping. The reflection looks fuzzy. They are now supposed to reapply the clear coat. What is the cause?

[image: photograph of paint job with hazy hood]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

While I'm no expert, if you need it to be reflective (hopefully to match the rest of the car), the new paint needs to be cut, buffed, & polished. Basically, you'd be flattening the clear coat which is on there to produce the clear shine that you're looking for. Right now the clear coat which was applied is very wavy, with a lot of peaks and valleys. It refracts the light and causes it to be unfocused. When you flatten it in the cut/buff/polish process, it smooths it out and brings the reflection into focus.

One of the issues may be, if the rest of the car is not cut/buffed/polished, you'll need to do it (or have it done) so it'll match. Otherwise you'll once again have mismatched panels on the car.

If you have not done this work yourself, I'd highly suggest you pay someone to do it for you. It is very easy to burn through the clear coat and screw the paint job up.

If you are full bore on doing this yourself, 3M makes the most widely used finishing products on the market (no affiliation). You'd need a full compliment of 3M products as well as a random orbit polisher and the various pads needed to do the job.